# Asp.net mvc testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing

CustomerController.cs:-

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        CustomerDataContext cs = new CustomerDataContext();
        var query = cs.Customers.Where(m => m.CustId == id).Select(m => m);
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        foreach (var q in query)
        {

            cust.CustId = q.CustId;
            cust.Name = q.Name;
            cust.Salary = q.Salary;
            cust.JoiningDate = q.JoiningDate;
        }
        return View("Details",cust);
    }
```

CustomerControllerTest.cs:-

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDetailsViewData()
{
    CustomerController controller = new CustomerController();
    var result = controller.Details(5) as ViewResult;
    Customer cust = result.ViewData.Model as Customer;
    Assert.AreEqual(5,cust.CustId);

}
```

My test fails and I get the following error messsage:
Test method MvcApplication1.Tests.Controllers.CustomerControllerTest.TestDetailsViewData threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What happens when you step through your code using a debugger?  What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: I think its not able to use the CustomerDataContext....Is the context available for testing?

Comment: Problem solved! It was the datacontext issue. I didnt have the connectionstring in my testproject. Now its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.
It just didn't have the connection string.